# Setting global environment variables in windows programatically

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

As i am frequently moving desktop, I use a lot of portable apps.

I would, however like to alter/add global environment variables programtaically 
on startup so that it is available to all consoles and windows in general.
Preferably It should work by running a script.

As the computer may be used later by another person the settings and variables must disappear when rebooted or powerloss occours.

Examples:
I would like to add `imagemagick` to the `PATH` on startup
Add to global `CLASSPATH` on startup.

Any surgestions?

Answer (score -2):

Just set the traditional way. Go to the System Applet, set your user variables.

Comment: This isn't an answer to the posted question. It's not "programtaically" and won't "forget" variables on reboot.

Comment: How do you know that "doesn't know how windows works"? He wants the system to forget the variables after a reboot. Do you suggest to set all the variables per windows gui after each reboot?

Comment: See whay I mean. There are machine variables, user variables, autoexec.bat variables (Win32 only), and volatile variables. User variables and autoexec.bat variables are PER USER and , like system variables, don't change. The Windows designers thought about this in the early 90s. Any pointless programming answer will do the same as the dialog (use setx in batch and write registry in any other language). Except it will do it over, and over, and over again for no reason.

Comment: You are right. SETX will achieve exactly the same. And this is why it's wron. SETX MyVar 123 will FOREVER set set MyVar to 123. The set variable will remain after a reboot. Now re-read the question. Do you notice this part: *As the computer may be used later by another person the settings and variables must disappear when rebooted or powerloss occours*? It's not said that a different user will use a different account. So if you set the variables PER USER it still won't hit the mark.

Comment: That's an unlikely requirement. But they stay forever with setx as it just writes registry keys (either per user or per machine) and sends a SettingsChange message to GRAPHICAL (ie non console) apps. As I said, users use the control panel, setup programs write registry keys either directly or indirectly.

Comment: Explorer reads the registry keys and is usually the app that starts most consoles.

Comment: To sum it: you've given an answer on how to set environment variables but neglected "programtaically" and "forget on reboot". Your answer covers one third of the question and even violates the other two parts --> useless --> downvote.

Comment: No but i have the **right** answer to the problem. How to configure his/her programming language so it doesn't affect other users.

Comment: Cause it is possible, just the wrong approach. Start cmd, type `set classpath=c:\something` then `taskkill /im explorer.exe` then `explorer.exe`, then start a console. BUT THIS IS STUPID and NOT WHAT THE USER WANTS.